# How to force Anaconda to display a hard disk during install?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, ssd, fedora

I'm trying to install [Fedora 26](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/F26_release_announcement) on a Gigabyte motherboard with an Intel SSD. Anaconda does not offer the Intel disk. The UEFI and the Terminal display the drive. Rescanning the hard disks in Anaconda does not help.

At this point, I have also performed the following steps to get Anaconda to offer the disk (the device is `sda`):

- `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/hda bs=512 count=32`
- `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=512 count=32`

And:

- Set disk to use ACHI to avoid Intel's S.M.A.R.T.

I don't know what else to do or try. I now want to force that miserable Anaconda to give the disk even when it does not want to.

How to force Anaconda to display the hard disk during install?

---

Here's the output of `fidsk -l`. My disk is `/dev/sda`, and its the one I am trying to use. The other disks are created by the Live CD.

```
$ cat ~/disks.txt
Disk /dev/sda: 149.1 GiB, 160041885696 bytes, 312581808 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop0: 1.3 GiB, 1370529792 bytes, 2676816 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes    

Disk /dev/loop1: 6.5 GiB, 6981419008 bytes, 13635584 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop2: 512 MiB, 536870912 bytes, 1048576 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/mapper/live-rw: 6.5 GiB, 6981419008 bytes, 13635584 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes    

Disk /dev/mapper/live-base: 6.5 GiB, 6981419008 bytes, 13635584 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Comment: Note that Fedora 26 has not been released yet — it is in Alpha status. (The announcement you linked to is just a draft someone started on the project wiki; it should have been marked as such.)

Comment: What _does_ Anaconda offer for install disks? None at all?

Comment: @mattdm - correct, there are none at all.

Comment: It's very strange that it shows up in `fdisk` but not in Anaconda. Is there anything in the anaconda logs (in `/tmp`)? Can you try with the Fedora 25 release version, to see if there's a regression? That seems most likely — and I'd like to find that out and catch it before the f26 actual release if possible!